# matching in list from set of values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and i have the following list:

```
list1 = ['switchport port-security maximum', 'switchport port-security aging']
```

And then i have a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {}

my_dict["GI2/1/1"] = [
'switchport port-security maximum 10', 
'switchport port-security maximum 3 vlan access', 
'switchport port-security maximum 1 vlan voice', 
'switchport port-security aging time 25', 
'switchport port-security aging type inactivity', 
'switchport port-security'
]

my_dict["GI2/1/2"] = [
'switchport port-security maximum 5', 
'switchport port-security maximum 5 vlan access', 
'switchport port-security maximum 3 vlan voice', 
'switchport port-security aging time 20', 
'switchport port-security aging type inactivity', 
'switchport port-security'
]


my_dict["GI2/1/3"] = [
'switchport port-security maximum 10', 
'switchport port-security maximum 3 vlan access', 
'switchport port-security maximum 1 vlan voice',  
'switchport port-security'
]
```

I am trying to find a way that i can search the values but it would need to match on both entries in list1

I have the following code, but it will match one and then break out, i know why its breaking out, but i can't figure out a way to force it to match on both entries and then break out. I know i can use all() to match everything exactly but i'm looking to just see if both those entries exist.

```
for name, val in my_dict.iteritems():
    for v in val:
        for i in list1:
            if i in v:
                print name
                break
```

The goal is to only output GI2/1/1 and GI2/1/2 because the GI2/1/3 doesn't match on both entries

Comment: What's the expected output? It's unclear to me what you mean by "search the values but it would need to match on both entries in list1".

Comment: I would like it output only GI2/1/1 and GI2/1/2 because the GI2/1/3 doesn't match on both

Comment: Just removing the `break` could work?

Comment: `break` is only breaking out of the `list1` loop, it should continue with the outer loops.

Comment: Josue has right, just remove the break.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a new `dict` that captures the results.

```
result = {key: set([item for item in list1 for things in val if item in things]) for key, val in my_dict.iteritems()}
#{'GI2/1/1': {'switchport port-security maximum', 'switchport port-security aging'}, 'GI2/1/2': {'switchport port-security maximum', 'switchport port-security aging'}, 'GI2/1/3': {'switchport port-security maximum'}}

result = [key for key, val in result.iteritems() if val == set(list1)]
#['GI2/1/1', 'GI2/1/2']
```

This can definitely be done in one line but I thought it might be easier to see what is going on with two steps. I am storing all matches in a list that gets turned into a `set` (remove duplicates) which is then compared against desired matches in `list1`.

EDIT: As @blhsing pointed out, `set` in python is unordered. Instead of making a `list` out of my values in `result`, I am making a `set` out of `list1` since I don't think OP will have duplicates in `list1`.

Another way would be to use `all` and check for all the items.

```
result = {key: set([item for item in list1 for things in val if item in things]) for key, val in my_dict.iteritems()}

result = [key for key, val in result.iteritems() if all([config in val for config in list1])]
# ['GI2/1/1', 'GI2/1/2']
```

EDIT #2: Because of OP's request in comments. Here is another potential way. (Motivated by @Josué Cortina's answer below).

```
my_list = [[
'switchport port-security maximum 10', 
'switchport port-security maximum 3 vlan access', 
'switchport port-security maximum 1 vlan voice', 
'switchport port-security aging time 25', 
'switchport port-security aging type inactivity', 
'switchport port-security'
], [
'switchport port-security maximum 5', 
'switchport port-security maximum 5 vlan access', 
'switchport port-security maximum 3 vlan voice', 
'switchport port-security aging time 20', 
'switchport port-security aging type inactivity', 
'switchport port-security'
], [
'switchport port-security maximum 10', 
'switchport port-security maximum 3 vlan access', 
'switchport port-security maximum 1 vlan voice',  
'switchport port-security'
]]

result = []
for sub_list in my_list:
    if all([True if any([config in item for item in sub_list]) else False for config in list1]):
        result.append(True)
    else:
        result.append(False)

#[True, True, False]
```

If we only have list of lists and want booleans to see if sub-list matches what we're looking for then above could be a possible solution.

Comment: Wow perfect, exactly what i was looking for, would it be possible to accomplish the same thing if they were both lists and one of them was not a dictionary. So if i didn't need to get the name i just needed to pass to lists and see if they match or not, how would i change the code for something like that?

Comment: Do you mean if both `list1` and `my_dict` were actually `list`s? So `my_dict` or more appropriately `my_list` is a list of lists?

Comment: correct if they were both lists with out the interface names, so i just want to see if the list of interface configs matches the list i am searching for?

Comment: So if the list looked like this my_list_1 = ['switchport port-security maximum 5', 
'switchport port-security maximum 5 vlan access', 
'switchport port-security maximum 3 vlan voice', 
'switchport port-security aging time 20', 
'switchport port-security aging type inactivity', 
'switchport port-security']                              and if it finds both matches with other list then print "matched" or something like that just to confirm it found both matches

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're asking about one list comparison. `set([item for item in list1 for things in my_list_1 if item in things]) == list1` will return `True` if both elements from `list` are in `my_list_1`. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect because sets are unordered in Python and `list(val)` will therefore not necessarily be equal to `list1`.

Comment: @blhsing You're correct. I completely forgot about that. I will update my answer for it.

Comment: Yes correct, that is what i am looking for, but without using a dictionary just using 2 lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `str.startswith` (if you dont care the position you can stick to using `in`) and combine it with `all` and `any`:

#### Code

```
for name, val in my_dict.iteritems():
    if all(any(v.startswith(l) for v in val) for l in list1):
        print name
```

You could use **regular expressions**, although it could be *overkilling*:

#### Code

```
import re

regexps = [re.compile(i) for i in list1]

for name, val in my_dict.iteritems():
    if all(any(regexp.match(v) for v in val) for regexp in regexps):
        print name
```

#### Output

```
GI2/1/1
GI2/1/2
```

I think both of this methods are pretty understandable: *you know what they do just having a look at them*

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood what you want but something like?

```
def cont(l,s):
    for i in l:
        if s in i:
            return True
    return False

for name, val in my_dict.iteritems():
        happy=True
        for i in list1:
            if not cont(val,i):
                happy=False
        if happy:
            print name
            break
```

(and just remove the break if you want to list all entries matching your constraints)

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate through `list1` to generate sets of keys in `my_dict` where any of the sub-lists of strings contains the given keyword in `list1`, and then use the `reduce` function to produce the desired output through set intersection:

```
reduce(set.intersection, ({n for n, l in my_dict.iteritems() if any(k in i for i in l)} for k in list1))
```

This returns:

```
set(['GI2/1/1', 'GI2/1/2'])
```